# How can I access my webcam in a docker container with an M1 macbook?

Tags: apple-silicon, docker

System Specs: macOS Monterey:12.2.1, MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021), Apple M1 Pro

I have found tutorials such as

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985648/access-camera-inside-docker-container
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852484/access-webcam-using-opencv-python-in-docker
- https://medium.com/@jijupax/connect-the-webcam-to-docker-on-mac-or-windows-51d894c44468

All of which are either:

- only for Linux
- only for Mac with intel
- depend on deprecated `docker-machine`
- use virtualbox

Comment: Even if the tutorials seem outdated: did you try to follow the instructions there, what was the result?

Comment: @nohillside For the tutorials that are for mac intel I usually got stuck when they needed me to install virtual box.  For the tutorials where I needed `docker-machine`, I got stuck because that tool doesn't exist anymore.